# String.Format Explanation

Tags: c#

I have little confusion in understanding, how the format is being generated for the following line.

Could any one provide me , how its renders the value in Format, With appropriate commas, being put at the right places in the figure.

```
writer.Write(string.Format("Your Estimated Loan Paymement+will be {0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}", + this.calcPayment(this._pv,1,2) ));
```

Here `calcPayment()` is a function returns a numeric value.  For example if it returns 2000.33, then it is outputed as $2,003.33.

I know it is doing the formating, but how?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want info on [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Breaking down the format string: `{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);Zero}`

There are 3 groups:

1. `$#,##0.00` - used when the argument (`this.calcPayment(this._pv,1,2)`
   in this case) is positive.
2. `($#,##0.00)` - used when arg is negative
3. `Zero` - used when arg is zero

`#` is a digit placeholder and `0` is a zero placeholder (padding).

See [this](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Kev for the edits. The inline code with '' is pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

The commas in the part of the format string such as `$#,##0.00` tell it whether to place commas (or, as @svick correctly states, "group separators), if needed. Here's a decent reference that describes the format codes half-way down the page: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

What's happening is the `Format` method (function) is using the format string as a template, and then adding in your additional data provided.

Comment: It doesn't tell it where to place commas, but where to place group separators. They happen to be commas in the English (and invariant) culture, but other cultures have different separators. Also, it doesn't say it where to place the separator, `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSize` decides that.

Comment: @svick: You're so correct. How boorishly American of me to assume commas. Good catch. :)

Comment: Also the semicolons(`;`) are dividing sections for positive numbers, negative numbers and zero (optional) patterns. Dot (`.`) indicates where the decimal separator is. `#` Specifies digits, `0` specifies mandatory digits (will be zero filled if not present). `$`,`()` and the other stuff will just be printed as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna hazard a guess that it's like this:

```
0: //this is telling it that this is the zero placeholder in the format string
$#,##0.00 //this is what happens if the value is above zero
($#,##0.00) //this is for values below zero
Zero //literal "Zero" output if the value is equal to zero
```

EDIT - reading about [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) from the link in @Jon's comment confirms that the three semicolon-delimited sections are indeed to specify formats for positive, negative, and zero values.

Comment: Not a comment on your answer, but given the information therein... Spitting out the string "Zero" instead of $0.00 is *very* odd... :S

Comment: `0:` is used to tell `String.Format` that this is the zeroeth string placeholder to be formatted. If two string formats were required then there would be `{0:...}` and `{1:....}`.